# Practical Math Problem: Ideal positioning for multiple 2-axis solar arrays

Tags: geometry, mathematical-astronomy

I live around 32°N latitude, and I am trying to figure out the optimal positioning for six 2-axis solar arrays so they don't interfere with each other when the sun is over 5° above the horizon. The arrays are roughly 8' square (2.4m) on a 5' (1.5m) stand, which means when the panels are nearly vertical at the beginning and ending of the day, they should cast a shadow from about 11' (3.3m) high in the air. To keep costs down I'd like to arrange these in a straight line with the intent to add another 6 arrays in the future, but as close together as possible as well. The straight line need not be along a cardinal direction, if there's better advantage to make the line go NE-SW or SE-NW. I have room to support this either way.

It seems there should be a relatively straightforward formula for figuring out how close and which orientation the arrays can be to each other and still get maximum direct sunlight in winter and summer, but frankly I don't even know where to start. Can someone here help me with this?

Comment: At your latitude, I guess, the decrease in efficiency by temperature would be more of a concern than the positioning.

Comment: I really, really hate uncommented downvotes, and I didn't do it. But I guess this was because you asked what, on other sites, would be considered as "asking for personal advice".

Comment: For satellites in space, where there is no shielding atmosphere and the sun is really hot, there are ways to direct the sunbeams to specialized AsGa solar cells that can take a rough shot. Don't know is anything like that has bee adapted to high insulation situations on earth.

Comment: well I wouldn't consider it "personal advice"... we are in fact talking about something applicable to most people interested in maximizing solar efficiency. And actually, solar cells perform better when cold.